# How to crawl and visualize historical twitter data?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am new to the field and trying to get some data from twitter for learning purposes, data visualization to be specific.

I want to see how the count of a certain topic (e.g. #WeTheNorth) changed over time in different regions of Canada, say April 13 to June 13. I am expecting to see the count increases as the time goes(As Raptors eventually won NBA championship), and I'd like to visualize the process of the data change in vertical bar or babble over the canada map over the months, in Tableau(or other tool).

I am currently facing problems that:
As I know, I can only use twitter API for crawling hashtags topic within one week. How can I crawl historical data of certain topic(#WeTheNorth) from April to June?
Do you have better suggestion to visualize the data?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau has a neat heat map tool that would be interesting show how the hashtag usage changes over time! As for collecting the data, I have only used a dataset for the **entirety** of hashtags as opposed to over time. I did stumble across this [page](http://socialmediadata.wikidot.com/) that has a whole list of different applications for data crawling multiple social media platforms. I imagine you will find this quite useful to your problem.

Comment: The heat map is pretty good starting point for my learning. But I don't have the "user time zone country" value (which is required to generate the heat map) somehow, even if most of data have "user location" data. Do you mind help to take a look of 
 the related question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956881/why-dont-my-twitter-data-have-a-user-time-zone-country Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok ill check it out